# Should "earlierly" be avoided?

Tags: word-choice

I found myself writing the word "earlierly" in my text editor and got a little red line underneath it. I must admit I was unsure about the spelling but was a bit surprised when I didn't find a spelling suggestion. I googled it and Google also suggested: "Did you mean: earlier?". Now I wonder, is "earlierly" a construction that should be avoided? Is it perhaps even a case of such a strong word as *incorrect*? And, if so, (I am sure you can understand *what* I am trying to say, but) how should I instead put what I am trying to say?

EDIT:
I wanted to use it a bit like: "I have earlierly introduced this problem". A bit like: "I have eagerly / happily / sadly introduced you to this"

Comment: Show us your sentence, at least.

Comment: [*Earlier* is an adverb as well as an adjective](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/early?q=earlier)

Comment: @AndrewLeach But of course! *Earlier* being the comparative degree of *early*, itself the adverb form from the adjective *ear*, an archaic spelling of *ere*. :)

Comment: Before is earlier. So _I have had this problem before_ is likely what you are looking for

Comment: Hm, yes but not if I want it to be clear that it is just once. Before sort of gives me the feeling that someone has seen the problem time after time after time. Also, come to think of it, I want to change the word had to introduced. (I seem to be complicated...) Another Edit pending... :)

Comment: @jonalv: If you said *I did [something] earlier* it would normally be in respect of something that only needs to be (or only *can* be) done once within the relevant time-frame. Usually the time-frame wouldn't be very long. You wouldn't, for example, normally say, *We don't want another Disneyland holiday because went earlier*. Note that you'd say *we went **once** before* if it was important to convey that it only happened once.

Comment: You seem to mean *too early* -- "I have introduced this problem **too early**", i.e, much before it is time for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the word "previously", as in, "I had this problem at a prior time". "Earlierly", while seeming like it'd be the word for "I had this problem at an earlier time", sadly, does not actually exist.

Comment: "sadly" is indeed the word. :)
However, don't you agree that the meaning of previous / previously is a bit different from the word earlier? Maybe there is nothing better... 
...sadly.

Comment: "earlier" is a synonym of "previously": http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earlier (scroll down to the thesaurus section)

Answer (score 1):

Not having seen any context, *early* is what you need, unless the context requires the superlative *the earliest.*  There is absolutely no such word as *earlierly*. *Early* or *the earliest* can be an adjective or an adverb. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I have had this problem earlier.

Allowed, as well as being the comparative form of *early*, *earlier* has a meaning "occuring previously".

> I have had this problem before.

Recommended, some favour using *earlier* only in the comparative sense. This has the same meaning, and avoids that objection.